# fcgi is still running after apache stopped

Tags: apache, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I use apache (FastCgiServer) to run 2 fcgi

---

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
...
<IfModule fastcgi_module>
    AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
    FastCgiIpcDir /fcgi
    FastCgiServer /usr/local/path/do_something.fcgi -processes 2 -idle-timeout 120
    FastCgiConfig -maxClassProcesses 128
</IfModule>
```

---

after stop apache

apache log : "AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart"

it seems that fcgi did not receive SIGTERM, so it is still running.

---

after restart apache

apache log : "FastCGI: process manager initialized"

spawn fcgi

so now, there are 4 fcgi processes